# WordPress Custom Post Type Functions Effecting Pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

ive got a problem which i cant seem to resole I know something in my function.php is causing my pages to cause 404 and cant find the custom template which is required.. Ive tried and searched High and low and still cant find the answer.. if any one can point me in the right direction that would be amazing. Heres my function.php http://pastebin.com/HFjP9cLh

I think its my custom post type which is causing the problem..

Thanks

Comment: Browse to your Settings>Permalinks to reset your permalinks structure.

Answer (score 0):

(Back up your file first)

When all else fails... remove all the functions you recently added. You want to get the site back to when it used to work.

Then slowly add in the missing functions one by one. Slowly you will isolate the issue to just one function.

Then do the same thing within the function. Remove all the lines of code and slowly add in the code until you get the part that is causing the issue. Once you know more of the specifics of what is happening you should have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look through all of the code but the first thing you need to do is remove `flush_rewrite_rules();`. That function should be called once and not every time the page is loaded.

Take it out entirely and then flush your permalinks by going to Settings -> Permalinks in the admin and hitting save.